# Why css files are imported correctly (from scss file) in "server" mode but not in "dist" mode? (yeoman, compass)

Tags: css, compass-sass, yeoman

I have an application build with yeoman and when I try to load a css file form the `main.scss`. When I run `"grunt server"` the linked css file is loaded. When I run `"grunt"` to build the dist it will not include the css file in the build version.

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it with a hack:

Add the following line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/flatstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
```

in your index.html file:

```
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/flatstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css"> <!-- Add this line -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Then in your grunt config file add a task type for the copy task:

```
flatstrap: {
    dest: '.tmp/bower_components/flatstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css',
    src: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/flatstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css'
}
```

That will be ran like this: `copy:flatstrap`

Now add the task type to the command:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'copy:flatstrap', // <--- add this
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'requirejs',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'modernizr',
    'copy:dist',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
]);
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do any modifying of the Gruntfile. All that should be necessary is adding the <link> reference between the `<!-- build ... -->` comment just as you had it.